# facebook commenting (other pages)

Tags: python, facebook

I've managed to post to my own page using facebooks access tokens and "fb" and "GraphAPI" in python. I'm wondering how could I comment on a post given any link to a page?

Comment: What do you mean by "any link to a page"?

Comment: basically any facebook page that you could like and not just limited to my own facebook page. F.ex if "Stack overflow" had a fan page on facebook the script should be able to post to it.  But it seems this is limited by the access tokens.

Comment: Whether or not you can post to other pages, depends on that page’s settings.